# Looking for a counter example of Dini derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

Could someone please give me an example of two functions $f$ and $g$ such that
$$D^+(f+g)\neq D^+(f)+D^+(g)$$
where $D^+f$ is the upper right derivative of $f$ (i.e. $D^+ f(x) = \limsup \limits_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$)?

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? You could come up with many examples yourself just by picking $f$ and $g$ to be any differentiable functions.

Comment: @ Philip Hoskins Ohh sorry, I was to mean not equal. I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

Take two functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{if }x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-x&\text{if }x\notin\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases},\qquad g(x)=-f(x).
$$
Then you can verify that $D^+(f+g)(0)=0$ and $D^+f(0)+D^+g(0)=2$.

Comment: Are you able to help out with this question of mine? :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2953842/proving-an-inequality-for-upper-right-hand-dini-derivatives